# Reporting on Duplicate Contacts

Tags: reporting, duplicate-management

I'm trying to figure out a way to build a report/query to show duplicate contacts by phone/email. The idea is to check if there are duplicate records with the same phone, but different email and vice versa.

I am searching for a declarative way.

Following the steps in the article below I've implemented Matching rule > Duplicate job and next I've created a custom report type Contacts with Duplicate Record Items, but it does not show each duplicate contact record and its email and phone, so it is not sufficient:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_jobs_run_and_manage.htm&type=5

Kindly suggest what can be done.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. SOQL described returned email, phone... from the duplicate records, but I need this information grouped by Duplicate Record Sets, since if the data is just a list, how can I know which duplicate records belong to one Duplicate Record set

Comment: _you can create a custom report type with the primary object being the object you want to find dupes in, and the secondary object being Duplicate Record Items_

Comment: create a Summary report and make Group by Phone/email

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question above - I've created custom report with primary Object "Contact" and secondary object "Duplicate Record Items", but it does not show each duplicate contact record and its email and phone, so it is not sufficient

Comment: @MayaPavlova The email and phone have to come form Contact, they're just fields on the report. Does not show each duplicate record - please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.